# help me with idea to understand: Determine the real number x for which the value of the expression $E(x)=\sqrt{x^2-4x+5}+\sqrt{x^2-6x+13}$ is minimum

Tags: calculus, optimization, exponentiation, radicals, maxima-minima

**PROBLEM**

Determine the real number x for which the value of the expression $E(x)=\sqrt{x^2-4x+5}+\sqrt{x^2-6x+13}$ is minimum.

**WHAT I THOUGHT OF**

So for $E(x)$ to be the minimum, we have to make $\sqrt{x^2-4x+5}$ and $\sqrt{x^2-6x+13}$ as small as possible $=>$ $x^2-4x+5$ and $x^2-6x+13$ have to be as small as possible.

I thought of writing

> $x^2-4x+5=x^2-4x+2^2+1=(x-2)^2+1$

> $x^2-6x+13=x^2-6x+3^2+4=(x-3)^2+4$

For $(x-2)^2+1$ to be the smallest $(x-2)^2$ has to be 0 $=>$ $x=2$

But, for $(x-3)^2+4$ to be the smallest $(x-3)^2$ has to be 0 $=>$ $x=3$

Now we can compare the numbers we get when $x=2$ and when $x=3$ and see which one is the smallest. That will be the answer. I don't know if what I thought of is correct. Can you help me solve the problem or tell me if what I thought of is good? Hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

Comment: No, that's not correct (or at least, not obviously correct).  There's no reason why the sum $f(x)+g(x)$ should be minimized at either the min of $f$ or the min of $g$.    The usual approach would be to solve $E'(x)=0$.  You could also square the function and hope that that makes it simpler to work with (not at all clear that it does).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Remarks*: We may use [Minkowski inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2960054/minkowski-inequality-proof-without-using-holders-inequality).

Here is a [similar problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4408230/question-about-finding-minima-using-minkowskys-inquality).

---

By Minkowski inequality, we have
$$E(x) = \sqrt{(x - 2)^2 + 1^2}
+ \sqrt{(3 - x)^2 + 2^2}
\ge \sqrt{(x - 2 + 3 - x)^2 + (1 + 2)^2} = \sqrt{10}.$$
(*Note*: Equality holds when $(x-2, 3 - x)$ and $(1, 2)$ are proportional, that is $\frac{x - 2}{1} = \frac{3 - x}{2}$ which results in $x = 7/3$. Indeed, $E(7/3) = \sqrt{10}$.)

Thus, the minimum of $E(x)$ is $\sqrt{10}$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Now I understand!

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 8):

Here's an approach that doesn't use calculus:

$E(x)=\sqrt{(x-2)^2+1}+\sqrt{(x-3)^2+4}$ is the sum of distances of $(x,0)$ from $(2,\pm1)$ and $(3,\pm2)$.

We have that $E(x)$ is minimised when the three points $(x,0),(2,\pm1)$ and $(3,\pm2)$ are collinear.

Checking the possibilities depending on the signs of the $y$ coordinates, we find $x=\frac73$ or $1$ in order for the points to be collinear. Comparing $E(1)$ and $E\left(\frac73\right)$, we find the minimum is $E\left(\frac73\right)=\sqrt{10}$.

Comment: Thank you soo much for your idea! Is really intresting. I just wanted to ask if you can explain the answer above, the one that use calculus, because id ont get it. Thank you again!

Comment: The other answer has rearranged $E'(x)=0$. If you take the derivative using the chain rule, and then move one term to the other side and multiply through by the denominators, you will get $(x-3)\sqrt{x^2-4x+5}=(2-x)\sqrt{x^2-6x+13}$.

Answer (score 3):

Taking the derivate:
$$(x-3)\sqrt{x^2-4x+5}+(x-2)\sqrt{x^2-6x+13}=0$$
Square both sides and obtain:
$$(x-3)^2\cdot(x^2-4x+5)=(x-2)^2\cdot(x^2-6x+13)\longleftrightarrow -3x^2+10x-7=0$$
So:
$$x=1\,\,\,\lor \,\,\,x=\frac{7}{3}$$
Can you finish it now?

Comment: One of the tags is "algebra-precalculus"

Comment: @Matteo How did you know that $$(x-3)\sqrt{x^2-4x+5}=(x-2)\sqrt{x^2-6x+13}$$?

Comment: You can differenciate $E(x)$

Comment: @Matteo I'm really sorry, but i stilll dont really understand.

Comment: @A.Goodier: yeah, sorry. Corrected.